# TypeError: GAN.training_step() missing 1 required positional argument: 'optimizer_idx'

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network, pytorch-lightning

When I start training my GAN model:

```
trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=20, devices=AVAIL_GPUS, accelerator='gpu')
trainer.fit(GAN(), MNISTDataModule())
```

I get this error: `TypeError: GAN.training_step() missing 1 required positional argument: 'optimizer_idx'`

I do have an optimizer_idx in my `training_step` function so I'm confused why I'm hitting this error. Could someone please help me debug this issue?

```
# GAN model using PyTorch lightning
class GAN(pl.LightningModule):
  # learning rate 0.002 (tweak this)
  # latent dimension 100
  def __init__(self, latent_dim=100, lr=0.002): 
    super().__init__()
    self.save_hyperparameters() # save self.hparams
    self.automatic_optimization = False  # activates manual optimization

    self.generator = Generator(latent_dim=self.hparams.latent_dim)
    self.discriminator = Discriminator()

    # random noise
    self.validation_z = torch.randn(6, self.hparams.latent_dim) # 6 images

  # forward pass
  #   - input tensor z
  def forward(self, z): 
    return self.generator(z)

  # loss function
  #   - predicted label y_hat
  #   - actual label y
  def adversarial_loss(self, y_hat, y):
    return F.binary_cross_entropy(y_hat, y)

  def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx, optimizer_idx):
    # tensor real_imgs 
    real_imgs, labels = batch

    # sample noise
    z = torch.randn(real_imgs.shape[0], self.hparams.latent_dim)
    z = z.type_as(real_imgs) # to use GPU

    # train generator: max log(D(G(z))) where z is random noise / fake images
    if optimizer_idx == 0:
      fake_imgs = self(z)
      y_hat = self.discriminator(fake_imgs)
      y = torch.ones(real_imgs.size(0), 1)
      y = y.type_as(real_imgs)
      g_loss = self.adversarial_loss(y_hat, y)
      log_dict = { "g_loss": g_loss }
      return { "loss": g_loss, "progress_bar": log_dict}

    # train discriminator: max log(D(x)) + log(1 - D(G(z)))
    if optimizer_idx == 1:
      # how well can discriminator label as real
      y_hat_real = self.discriminator(real_imgs)
      y_real = torch.ones(real_imgs.size(0), 1)
      y_real = y_real.type_as(real_imgs)
      real_loss = self.adversarial_loss(y_hat_real, y_real)

      # how well can discriminator label as fake 
      y_hat_fake = self.discriminator(self(z).detach()) # detach: creates a new tensor that is detached from computational graph (since we already do fake_imgs = self(z))
      y_fake = torch.zeros(real_imgs.size(0), 1)
      y_fake = y_fake.type_as(real_imgs)
      fake_loss = self.adversarial_loss(y_hat_fake, y_fake)
      d_loss = (real_loss + fake_loss) / 2
      log_dict = { "d_loss": d_loss }
      return { "loss": d_loss, "progress_bar": log_dict, "log": log_dict } # log in case we want to use tensorboard

  def configure_optimizers(self):
    lr = self.hparams.lr
    opt_generator = torch.optim.Adam(self.generator.parameters(), lr=lr)
    opt_discriminator = torch.optim.Adam(self.discriminator.parameters(), lr=lr)
    # return empty list [] in case we use scheduler
    return [opt_generator, opt_discriminator]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GPU for the training and you have multiple optimizers, I think you need to use Manual Optimization in pytorch lightning.

I think below links can help.

https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/common/optimization.html

https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/notebooks/lightning_examples/basic-gan.html